# Closed all connections and still getting "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"

Tags: c#, sql, connection, database-connection, sqldatareader

This is my code for which I am getting the above said error when trying to delete the tournament. Since Tournament is associated with an image, the code calls the ImageDeletion function first and then the tournament count function before deleting the whole tournament.

```
protected void LVTournament_ItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {
   if (Session["TournId"] != null)
    {
       int ClubId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["ClubDetails"]["ClubId"]);
       int TournId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["TournId"]);
       SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(constr);
       SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(constr);
       ImageDeletion(TournId);
       string querydelTour = "DELETE FROM Tournaments WHERE TournamentId = @TournId";
       SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(querydelTour, con1);
       cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TournId", TournId);
       con1.Open();
       cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con1.Close();
       UpdateTourCount(ClubId);
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Success", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Tournament Deleted...')</script>");
       Response.Redirect("TournamentView.aspx");
     }
   else
     {
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Popup", "SessionExpires();", true);
       return;
      }
 }
```

The Image Deletion function is

```
private void ImageDeletion(int TournId)
  {
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
     SqlCommand cmdchk = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) Valid FROM TournamentImages WHERE  TournamentId= @TournId");
     cmdchk.Connection = con;
     cmdchk.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TournId", TournId);
     con.Open();
     int Count = (int)cmdchk.ExecuteScalar();
     for (int i = 0; i <= Count; i++)
        {
          string query = "SELECT ImagePath FROM TournamentImages WHERE TournamentId = @TournId";
          SqlCommand cmddel = new SqlCommand(query, con);
          cmddel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TournId", TournId);
          SqlDataReader reader = cmddel.ExecuteReader();
          while (reader.Read())
            {
              string FilePath = reader[0] as string;
              string path = Server.MapPath(FilePath);
              FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
                if (file.Exists)
                  {
                     file.Delete();
                   }
             }
          }
        con.Close();
     }
```

And the tournament count function is

```
protected void UpdateTourCount(int ClubId)
 {
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
  string Query = "UPDATE TournamentCount SET Count = Count + 1 WHERE ClubId =@ClubId";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubId", ClubId);
  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
  }
```

I have close the connections then and there and still I am getting this error.

Kindly mention me where am I making the mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the *using* block to cope issues like this. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your error message should give you a tip what is going on. It says "There is already an open **DataReader** ...". So you have closed the connections, but not the reader.

You should call method [`Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close(v=vs.110).aspx) after you have used reader:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmddel.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    string FilePath = reader[0] as string;
    string path = Server.MapPath(FilePath);
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
reader.Close();   // <- close the reader
```

`SqlDataReader` implements `IDisposable`, so you can alternativelly use `using` statement to achieve the same result:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmddel.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string FilePath = reader[0] as string;
        string path = Server.MapPath(FilePath);
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine now... I just inserted "reader.Close(); " to the Image insertion function. Thank you mate